# Rewrite URL change

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need some help with my rewrite modules on my page. I would like to change my URL like i write under:

```
http://www.3esdesign.com/portfolio/budynki?projekt=koncepcja-hotelu-roznow
```

i want to my link looks like

```
http://www.3esdesign.com/portfolio/budynki/koncepcja-hotelu-roznow
```

Where "koncepcja-hotelu-roznow" will be diffrent to other pages.

This is my actually htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domena.com(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domena.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'm trying this code in main directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ portfolio/$1.php?projekt=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^3esdesign.com(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.3esdesign.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Serwer logs:

```
[Tue Feb 07 11:25:31.379189 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 55:tid 139960610965248] [client 82.115.92.43:59639] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/parkwnetrz/ftp/3esdesign/portfolio/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.php4,index.php3,index.php5,index.cgi,index.pl,index.htm,index.html,index.shtm,index.shtml,index.wml,default.htm,default.html,index_default.html,index_default.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Tue Feb 07 11:16:50.028891 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 27:tid 139960527038208] [client 185.85.239.157:58525] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Tue Feb 07 11:13:52.304869 2017] [core:alert] [pid 55:tid 139960594179840] [client 82.115.92.43:59262] /home/parkwnetrz/ftp/3esdesign/.htaccess: Invalid command '^portfolio/([\\w-]+)/([\\w-]+)$', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Tue Feb 07 11:13:41.164930 2017] [core:alert] [pid 55:tid 139960602572544] [client 40.77.167.42:17519] /home/parkwnetrz/ftp/3esdesign/.htaccess: Invalid command '^portfolio/([\\w-]+)/([\\w-]+)$', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Tue Feb 07 11:13:16.105461 2017] [core:alert] [pid 27:tid 139960476681984] [client 82.115.92.43:59249] /home/parkwnetrz/ftp/3esdesign/.htaccess: Invalid command '^portfolio/([\\w-]+)/([\\w-]+)$', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Tue Feb 07 11:13:15.897717 2017] [core:alert] [pid 27:tid 139960485074688] [client 82.115.92.43:59249] /home/parkwnetrz/ftp/3esdesign/.htaccess: Invalid command '^portfolio/([\\w-]+)/([\\w-]+)$', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Tue Feb 07 11:13:15.704692 2017] [core:alert] [pid 27:tid 139960527038208] [client 82.115.92.43:59249] /home/parkwnetrz/ftp/3esdesign/.htaccess: Invalid command '^portfolio/([\\w-]+)/([\\w-]+)$', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Tue Feb 07 11:13:15.465792 2017] [core:alert] [pid 27:tid 139960535430912] [client 82.115.92.43:59249] /home/parkwnetrz/ftp/3esdesign/.htaccess: Invalid command '^portfolio/([\\w-]+)/([\\w-]+)$', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Tue Feb 07 11:13:14.926891 2017] [core:alert] [pid 27:tid 139960569001728] [client 82.115.92.43:59249] /home/parkwnetrz/ftp/3esdesign/.htaccess: Invalid command '^portfolio/([\\w-]+)/([\\w-]+)$', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Tue Feb 07 11:05:21.923535 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 55:tid 139960468289280] [client 82.115.92.43:49537] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/parkwnetrz/ftp/3esdesign/portfolio/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.php4,index.php3,index.php5,index.cgi,index.pl,index.htm,index.html,index.shtm,index.shtml,index.wml,default.htm,default.html,index_default.html,index_default.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with below conditions seperatly,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ portfolio/$1.php?projekt=$2 [L]
```

Comment: what is the error? and where are you applying the htaccess

Comment: so you are using .htaccess in portfoilio directory i guess?

Comment: .htaccess is in main directory, u can try on my server:



[link](http://www.3esdesign.com/portfolio/budynki?projekt=koncepcja-hotelu-roznow)

Comment: Please check your error logs and also put in question too.